# Today is April 26th, and I still haven't received any response concerning my application to 2 Ph.D. programs. Is this normal?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, application

I also tried contacting both schools, but they fail to give me a clear answer concerning the status of my application. Also tried looking on the application page on the site of both universities, but no result there as well. Can I consider myself rejected at this point or is there still any hope?

Both universities are in the US and abide to the 15th April resolution according to https://cgsnet.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/CGS_April15_Resolution_Apr22.pdf which makes all offers of graduate school financial aid valid until April 15th. The applications were due in mid-December for programs beginning in Fall 2022.

Comment: @jonesy Have you checked your spam folder? What does "fail to give me a clear answer" mean? Did you get *any* answer?

Comment: @Bryan Krause I have been checking in the last few weeks, but it might be the case that I missed the email in march and it got deleted after a while. In fact, I had missed the email from another university, but they quickly sent me the decision email back after I inquired. As for those other two I mentioned, one told me to read their FAQ regarding response time (not helpful) and the other told me (after 2 weeks I sent the email) that decision dates vary for each program and I should try contacting the program directly, and also that if a decision was made I would receive an email.

Comment: @jonesy For the first one, when did you ask them? For the second, did you follow up with the program directly?

Comment: @Bryan Krause Both universities abide to the 15th res. (already edited the OP). For the first university, I asked them on April 12th, then I sent them another email and they didn't respond anymore. For the second one, I received their late response today, I might try asking the program directly, but 4 days ago I did contact a professor member of the admission committee for this program, and he told me it was unlikely I would get an offer at this point.

Comment: I sympathize with you that getting that canned response on April 12th is incredibly frustrating... For the second program, it is similarly frustrating that they did not respond to you earlier, but it does seem you've gotten a clear response from them: it is unlikely (effectively zero probability, this is just a friendly way to say it) that you will get an offer from them.

Comment: @Bryan Krause regarding the "unlikely" response, Im still not totally sure, neither was this professor. He asked me in the email some other details regarding the application. This program is offered in multiple internal school/departments in this university, and he asked me to specify these details because each possibility follows different processes and the response times varies, even though its the same program (this is unique to this university and super confusing, I know). I then replied with these details, but still no answer from him.

Comment: Indeed, that seems...unnecessarily complicated. Presumably there is some central point of contact that keeps things orderly, but perhaps that professor doesn't know who that point of contact is. It would certainly explain why they have failed to communicate a decision, though, if they are so disorganized. Maybe better not to be a student there, after all...

Answer (score 5):

I sympathize with you that getting a canned response "to read their FAQ regarding response time" on April 12th is incredibly frustrating, though it's likely your message did not go to someone with knowledge of your specific application if you sent your mail to a general graduate school office. Admissions decisions in the US are typically made by individual programs: contact the program to see if you've missed a message. Unfortunately, even if they did intend to accept you, it may be too late now.

Ordinarily, application decisions in the US are given out by the beginning of April at the *latest*, to give students a chance to consider their options before the April 15 deadline. If you are waitlisted, then it is possible to hear a spot has opened up *after* April 15th, when students who have accepted other offers would notify schools by, but you should have been informed you are on a waitlist already.

For the second program, it is similarly frustrating that they did not respond to you earlier, but it does seem you've gotten a clear response from them: it is unlikely (effectively zero probability, this is just a friendly way to say it) that you will get an offer from them.

I would consider both of these to be rejections at this point; when I was applying to grad schools in the US it was typical to get both a physical mail and emailed response, and I also received a personal phone call from accepting programs. I assume these standards are more or less the same today, though some programs may only communicate rejections one way. If they failed to send one, it's their fault; if you failed to receive it, it may be your fault, but neither really changes the admissions situation for you. I hope you've accepted your other offer if it was suitable to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rejected you will most likely get a clear statement of it. I'd guess that they are still processing applications and only starting to make offers. Lack of a clear answer is probably a positive sign. Giving a clear statement helps them avoid answering unfruitful queries. But not all universities have optimal policies.

OTOH, it is possible that they are making offers and that you aren't at the top of the list. But the crystal ball is cloudy.

It is a mistake to make assumptions about things, but also good to keep other options open.

If you only applied to two schools, however, you have sub-optimized, especially if they are similar.

Comment: I applied to 6 universities: 3 rejected me, 1 accepted me, and also those other 2.

Comment: Getting no reply at all seems quite odd. If they are waitlisted then it is to the benefit of the department to tell them that. Similarly telling them 'yes' or 'no' is beneficial to all parties.